# RestSharp request sending DateTime.MinValue when sending object

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

When sending an object, either in the body or as parameter using RestSharp, the DateTime object properties are recevied as MinValue (or null for DateTime nullable properties).

My example:

```
internal static int RequestWithObjectParam<T>(
    T parameter, string resource, string httpMethod, out string jsonResponseData)
{
    var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);

    var request = new RestRequest(resource, HttpMethod.VerbStringToHttpVerb(httpMethod));
    request.AddObject(parameter);

    var result = client.Execute(request);

    jsonResponseData = result.Content;

    return (int)result.StatusCode;
}
```

The object sent contains a property as simple DateTime:

```
public DateTime LastModification { get; set; }
```

And this field is set just to DateTime.Now before being sent:

```
lastModification: DateTime.Now,
```

Finally the ActionMethod:

```
public HttpStatusCode PostParking(Guid key, Parking newParking)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that they're set to a sensible value when they're sent. Do you have the sending code?

Comment: I set them as DateTime.Now:

lastModification: DateTime.Now,